# sails.js angulajs file post 404 (Not Found) error node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sails.js

i am using sailsjs and want to upload files using

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() 
xhr.open("POST", "/admin/images/upload")
```

routes:

```
 'post /admin/images/upload' :{
        controllers   :'ImagesController',
        action        :'upload'
  }
```

but when i post it returns 404 not found error ,and it never enters to that controller,
this code was prefectly working with simple node.js and i tried other jquery plugin for file upload but same 404 page not found error reciving from server

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `controllers` to `controller` in your route declaration:

```
'post /admin/images/upload' :{
        controller   :'ImagesController',
        action       :'upload'
 }
```

Or you could use the shortcut:

```
'post /admin/images/upload' : 'ImagesController.upload'
```